# PyYAML failure to install with PyAutoLens on Ubuntu

Tags: distutils, pyyaml

I am trying to install PyAutoLens on my Ubuntu 20.04-running laptop using pip/pip3. It all seems to go well then I get the following and all dependencies seem to be satisfied until:

```
    Installing collected packages: PyYAML, zeus-mcmc, SQLAlchemy, pyswarms, pyprojroot,gprof2dot, emcee, 
    dynesty, dill, corner, autoconf, colossus, autofit, autoarray, autogalaxy, autolens
    Attempting uninstall: PyYAML
    Found existing installation: PyYAML 5.1.2
    ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and thus
    we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I am running Python 3.8. Research shows that distutils will be deprecated in future.  I realise that I could use pip with --ignore, but that doesn't seem very tidy to me.

How can I get round  this? Digging around doesn't produce much - but of course I may have missed something! I don't think that this is a pip issue, it appears to be a distutils issue.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Check your version numbers first!!

This issue was resolved by going to Python 3.10 and doing a fresh install. This resolved a number of conflicts that had arisen on this system between Ubuntu, Anaconda and Pip.